# PHPMailer() SSL/crypto Support Failure

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer() to send mail using PHP with host `smtp.gmail.com` (port 465). However, I always get this error message:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP g7sm2712458obh.2 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [125.5.102.200] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [streams.crypto]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in ##### on line 200
```

I have searched for some solution but it always say that I have to edit `php.ini` file. I don't know how to edit such document since I am running the code in a hosted server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are connecting to a TLS port, not an SSL one. I suggest you base your code on [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided with PHPMailer. Use `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587`.

Beyond that, it looks like you may not have SSL support enabled in your PHP - check `php -m` output for `openssl`, and see [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: Thank you for this! Awesome troubleshooting guide.